# Iterating inside a class or iterating the class instance?

Tags: python, oop, loops

This is a general question about object-oriented programming and I will illustrate it using the following simplified example.

There is a file uploaded every day inside an FTP site. The files are given a name according to the date they are uploaded. So, we have Day1.txt, Day2.txt, and so on.
I have created a class that downloads one file at a time. So when I call an instance of this class, a file is downloaded according to the given argument. For example:
`downloading_class("2")` will download `Day2.txt`.

Now, I want to expand the functionality of my program by downloading a range of files from a start date to an end date. Obviously I will use a `for` loop.
My question is: is it a good practice to integrate the `for` loop inside the class and then call an instance of the class with something like this:

```
downloading_class("2","10")
```

or

write a for loop outside the class and integrate the instance within the loop:

```
for i in range(start,end):
    downloading_class(i)
```

Why is it better the one or the other?

Comment: The question is, how much are you doing it? If you do something repeatedly, abstract it out into a function. If you are only doing it once, it's probably not worth doing so.

Comment: @Lattyware The program intents to download a user-defined wide range of files (e.g. 100) every time it is used. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Normally, something that you call with an argument that does something and then goes away isn't a class, it's a function. Sure, you can create a class that acts like a function, or one whose objects act like functions, but… why would you?

Comment: @abarnert Actually, my class contains 4 methods (incl. __init__). Maybe I am missing something here, but I am just asking whether looping should be done inside or outside the class.

Comment: @ArditSulce: If your real code looks like what you've written here, your `__init__` method is being used purely for side-effects; the object being constructed isn't even stored anywhere. This is _occasionally_ reasonable, when the real point of having a class is to provide a hook for customization (e.g., with `threading.Thread`), but in general, it means something is wrong with your object model. And asking us how to expand an object model that makes no sense is not the best way to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define some operations that are performed on a range of files, then it could make sense to have a class that represents a range of files. This doesn't mean that you should integrate this into the class that represents one file, though, you're allowed to write two classes!

However, be careful to think about whether these operations on a range of files really do apply only to a *contiguous range in date order*, as opposed to applying to any old collections of files in any order. If they can apply to any old collections of files, then you would probably be better off sticking with your class to represent a single file. Then write some other functions that operate on lists (or other iterables) of files, for the any-old-collection operations, and for convenience write a function to return the most common case (a range in date order). Then your code might look like:

```
for file in download_range("2", "10"):
    do_something_with_one(file)
```

or for the cases where you're doing a pre-defined any-old-collection operation:

```
do_something_with_many(download_range("2", "10"))
```

In both cases, you can replace `download_range("2", "10")` with `(downloading_class("2"), downloading_class("4"), downloading_class("6"))`, or with `reversed(download_range("2", 10"))`, or with `(file for file in download_range("2", "10") if file.size() < 1000)`. Or anything you like, which is the goal of designing APIs that can be used flexibly.

Comment: Instantiating multiple times instead of iterating within the class would probably be more compatible with the multiprocessing module?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the performance in this case much been affected by instantiating the object, but generally, I think it's better to instantiate once and use N time instead of instantiate and use N times.